# How to select 30 questions from questions table with the condition like sum of marks should be 120

Tags: eclipse, sqlite

I have table containing columns like

[image: questions]

Now my requirement is to fetch 30 random questions and also the total of the marks should be 120.

I know how to fetch 30 random questions i.e. by using following query:

select * from questions order by random limit 30

I also know how to find sum of the marks column i.e. by using following query:

select sum(marks) from questions

But I am stuck at how to check condition that the 30 random questions that i am bringing are those whose marks column total is 120.

Answer (score 0):

One way I thought of tackling this (without getting into recursion or looping until you get the right total) is that if you know the spread of the marks, you could pull out random lists for a set number of each.

Eg. (marks*n) + (marks*n) + (marks*n) = 120 aka (4*20)+(5*8) = 120 marks

and in SQL :

```
select * from
(
    select * from questions where marks = 4 order by random limit 20
        union all
    select * from questions where marks = 5 order by random limit 8
) a
```

I suppose you could even derive a mathematical formula to randomize the spread to give you a truly random selection.

Hope this helps.

Paul P

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) (where weight and value are equal for all objects).

Solving it practically impossible in SQL; you should just read all question marks and implement the [solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0.2F1_Knapsack_Problem) in your code.